# Access VBA - After Update Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

Need Assistance in generating a specific value to display on a form using vba on a Microsoft Access Form depending on how many combo boxes have a name.

For example if the User selects, 'Tom' the project will cost 10, if Tom and Jerry are selected then 20, if Tom Jerry and George then 30. So I want 'some other field' to populate a fixed amount based on how many of these combo boxes have values.

Please assist and thank you!

```
X = 10 * (7 - (Abs(IsNull(Me!txtTestDirector.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtSystemOperator.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtTestEngineer1.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtTestEngineer2.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtAnalyst.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtTrainee1.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!txtTrainee2.Value)))
```

Comment: A combobox always has a name. So?

Comment: I'm not trying to put names into a combo box. If there is a fixed value per name based on a certain location how can those be summed up through a variable each time the combo box is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Value = 10 * (TotalCoboboxCount - (Abs(IsNull(Me!Combobox1.Value)) + Abs(IsNull(Me!Combobox2.Value)) + ... + Abs(IsNull(Me!ComboboxN.Value))))
```

Comment: The answer you provided worked GREAT, all it needed was an extra ' ) ' at the end of the code, thank you!!!

Comment: Ah, thanks, it was air-code. It has been added. Then please mark as answered,